# Celery worker never ready (hangs) with flask

Tags: celery

I have a tasks module in which, we basically do the following:

```
def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(app.import_name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task
    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
          abstract = True
              def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                   with app.app_context():
                      return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery

@celery.task(name="tasks.add")
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

The celery app is then created as so:

```
celery = tasks.make_celery(app)
```

Where app is a flask app

For configs I am using:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = str(os.environ.get("CELERY_BROKER_URL", 'redis://localhost:6379/0'))
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = str(os.environ.get("CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND", 'redis://localhost:6379/0'))
```

I am following the tutorial in http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/celery/

However, when I run the worker, I see that it is starting, and it lists my add task then it hangs (never displays the ready message).

Comment: For those of us who don't know what "celery" is, this is a very unusual question title :P

Comment: What's the output when you start the worker with DEBUG loglevel (-l option)?

Comment: Basically I just see the registered task list, then the worker hangs.

Comment: @lazyfunctor running with debug, this is the last thing I see [2014-04-01 23:04:21,446: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Pool before it hangs...

Comment: I don't really know what celery is, and when I saw this in the questions list, I thought you were 100% mad.. now I _know_ the guy that made the lib is.

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing identical symptoms and was able to narrow the problem down to Flask-SocketIO. While this probably isn't directly what's causing OP's problem, it could be related or relevant for future visitors with identical symptoms.

I documented my problem here: https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/61

Also, not enough reputation to post as comment.